# Hide Store Procedures

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way that we can Hide Store Procedures in SQL Server from users?

Comment: from all users or specific users?

Comment: What version of SQL server? Schemas are probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt the text of the stored procedure, if that is what you mean.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table
END
```

The encryption is not unbreakable, but at least it is a first line of defence.

Comment: Encrypting Stored procedures is also a good way of preventing programmers (or ones self) "tweaking" things on the fly, rather than updating source scripts etc. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2005 and above, don't give them permissions. Then, ["Metadata visibility"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113%28SQL.90%29.aspx) means it's not visible and not runnable. It makes no sense to want to hide them but give them permissions.

Note: db_owners and syadmins will always see them.

Otherwise your only option is to encrypt the stored procedure as mentioned (which is easily defeated using free tools).